react useEffect handleKeyDown dubbleing output with every entry
every input results in doubble the amount of outputs each time resulting in getting stuck in a long loop after just a few inputs.
this is the code
  const [direction,setDirection] = useState(Array(1).fill(0));
  const directions = ["botNorth","botEast","botSouth","botWest"];
  const [squares, setSquares] = useState(Array(5).fill().map(()=> Array(5).fill(null)));

  useEffect(()=> {
    const handleKeyDown = (e) =>{
      e = e || window.event;
      const nextSquares = squares.slice();
      var nextDirection = direction.slice();
      console.log(e.which);
      if (e.keyCode == '38') {
          // up arrow
      }
      else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
         // left arrow
         nextDirection[0]--;
         if (nextDirection[0] < 0) {
          nextDirection[0] = 3;
         }

      }
      else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
         // right arrow
      }
      setDirection(nextDirection);
      nextSquares[location[0]][location[1]] = <img className={directions[nextDirection[0]]} src={bot}/>;
      setSquares(nextSquares);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    };
    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown, true);
});

this is the resulting error each key was only pressed once

I've tryed moving the the add and remvove listeners around both inside and outside the function but it doesnt seem to make a difference
when i comment out both setSquare() and setDirection() it outputs twice per input instead of doubbleing each time

Does this answer your question? react useEffect hook cleanup

One thing to know is that since you are setting options when adding the event listener, you also need that same option when removing.  So document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown, true); needs document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown, true);  Otherwise the cleanup function looks like it is correct.  sorry misspoke here, the cleanup need to be moved out of handleKeyDown.  The useEffect needs to return the cleanup function.
I would also add a dependency array to your useEffect with these arguments setDirection, setSquares, squares, direction. That will limit the use effect from firing on every render, and will only fire when squares or direction change value
  useEffect(()=> {
    const handleKeyDown = (e) =>{
      e = e || window.event;
      const nextSquares = squares.slice();
      var nextDirection = direction.slice();
      console.log(e.which);
      if (e.keyCode == '38') {
          // up arrow
      }
      else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
         // left arrow
         nextDirection[0]--;
         if (nextDirection[0] < 0) {
          nextDirection[0] = 3;
         }

      }
      else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
         // right arrow
      }
      setDirection(nextDirection);
      nextSquares[location[0]][location[1]] = <img className={directions[nextDirection[0]]} src={bot}/>;
      setSquares(nextSquares);

    };
    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown, true);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown, true);
}[setDirection, setSquares, squares, direction]);

That update to the useEffect should get you most of the way there.  I am still occasionally seeing duplicate events.  I feel like adding and removing the event listener each time state changes is probably not the best way to go about it. I would only add the event listener on the first render, and would not read state in the event listener.  I would useRefs that I could mutate directly from the event listener, then a callBack that would inform react that state had changed.

changing it to document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown, true); had no effect

Hmm.. according to the docs it's necessary. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener .  Have you logged the cleanup function to verify that it is running?

Do squares and direction both need to be stateful? Specifically squares, is it being used anywhere besides this useEffect?

Oh, I just noticed that the cleanup is inside of the event.  Sorry missed that.  Move  return () => document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown); one level up outside of the current closure.

ah there we go, did that and changed it to thanks return () => {document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown, true);document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);};
